# Creating a schedule in VersionOne using REST returns 404

Tags: c#, rest, post, versionone

I'm trying to create a schedule in VersionOne using the REST API (using C#).  Per their "Create a New Asset" page, I issued a request to get the XML, set the 2 properties (TimeboxLength and TimeboxGap) and sent it back.  The response ends up as **The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**

I've tried creating it at the base url, and at the scope-level url, and not joy.

My code looks like this:

```
request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/rest-1.v1/Data/",url)) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType="application/xml";
using (StreamWriter rs = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    //This string is the populated xml skeleton retrieved from the website 
    string schedule = string.Concat("<?xml version='1.0' encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "<Asset href=\"/WUP/rest-1.v1/New/Schedule\">",
        "   <Attribute name=\"TimeboxLength\" act=\"set\">42 Days</Attribute>",
        "   <Attribute name=\"TimeboxGap\" act=\"set\">2 Days</Attribute>",
        "</Asset>");
    rs.Write(schedule);
    rs.Flush();
    rs.Close();
}
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(we.Status.ToString());
}
```

I don't think it's an oauth issue, and just using the credential cache is working right now.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* just noticed you said 404 so that's probably the path.  Make sure its /rest-1.v1/Data/Schedule -- and case matters!

You're so very close.  First, if you check meta (the keeper of all truth), by default, you need 3 things.  That's found here...

V1instance/meta.v1/Schedule?xsl=api.xsl

So just add something like this to your payload

```
string schedule = string.Concat("<?xml version='1.0' encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "<Asset>",
  --->  "   <Attribute name=\"Name\" act=\"set\">Password Reset Schedule</Attribute>",
        "   <Attribute name=\"TimeboxLength\" act=\"set\">42 Days</Attribute>",
        "   <Attribute name=\"TimeboxGap\" act=\"set\">2 Days</Attribute>",
        "</Asset>");
```

And you should be good to go.  Also, no need for the href in the asset element, that's returned on requests if you need it (useful when there's a lot of stuff coming back)

Comment: Thanks for getting back.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  After adding the missing name attribute, I got the same issue.  I asked our VersionOne administrator, and he was talking about using the security token.  I didn't thing that was necessary, since we are using integrated security.  Could that be my issue?

Comment: Access token you could use.  Might be worth trying basic too.  What's the error you're getting? (the payload)